# How to retrieve the body of an Oracle procedure or function

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

What I'd like to be able to do is retrieve the schema information for subprograms, functions, package specifications and package bodies from an Oracle 9i database so that I can present them to the user in a C# client using the classes in the System.Data.OracleClient namespace.

So far, I've been able to display the high level schema data far faster than Java applications can, but the packages and functions are beyond my grasp. I can show the columns, their types, the indexes, table- and column level comments, and all sorts of *really* useful information in really useful ways. Now, if I could just get to the procedures.

Comment: I feel your pain - hated the Oracle java IDE when I was forced to use that DB.  Good luck!

Comment: Have a look at this as well by Eve Andersson    
[link](http://www.eveandersson.com/writing/data-model-reverse-engineering)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Query the data dictionary table ALL_SOURCE http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch2124.htm#1300946

Answer (score 6):

Does this help?  Not clear whether you wanted to get this via System.Data.OracleClient or via SQL?

```
SELECT TEXT
FROM   ALL_SOURCE
WHERE  NAME = <proc_name>
AND    OWNER = <schema>
```

Comment: At some point, I have to get the data out of Oracle, so there will be some SQL involved. If this does the trick, I'll send ya some girl scout cookies.