# How to see PL/SQL Stored Function body in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a stored function in Oracle database pAdCampaign.fGetAlgoGroupKey.
How to see the code of this function.?

Comment: is "pAdCampaign" the schema or a package?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET: How to retrieve the body of an Oracle 9i PL/SQL procedure or function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554115/net-how-to-retrieve-the-body-of-an-oracle-9i-pl-sql-procedure-or-function)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If is a package then you can get the source for that with:

```
    select text from all_source where name = 'PADCAMPAIGN' 
    and type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
    order by line;
```

Oracle doesn't store the source for a sub-program separately, so you need to look through the package source for it.

Note: I've assumed you didn't use double-quotes when creating that package, but if you did , then use

```
    select text from all_source where name = 'pAdCampaign' 
    and type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
    order by line;
```

Comment: If you're selecting from ALL_SOURCE you should include the OWNER in the WHERE clause.

Comment: for showing a function, the `type` you should use is `FUNCTION`

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT text 
FROM all_source
where name = 'FGETALGOGROUPKEY'
order by line
```

alternatively:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('FUNCTION', 'FGETALGOGROUPKEY')
from dual;
```

Comment: For you first answer query it's giving an error
ORA-00904: "PROCEDURENAME": invalid identifier.

Comment: It's returning null. But I am sure this function is there/exist. I am calling this function from Java code or from SQL code it's returning the value as expected.

Comment: @VallabhPatade Maybe you created it using double quotes, and the name is now case-sensitive? Are you connected with the user that owns the function?

Comment: @VallabhPatade: just saw that you are actually talking about a package function, not a standalone function (which you should have mentioned right away). See DazzaL's answer then.

Comment: dbms_metadata.get_ddl only works for your own objects or for SYS, so the first solution sometimes returns text where the second doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use DBMS_METADATA:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('FUNCTION', 'FGETALGOGROUPKEY', 'PADCAMPAIGN') 
from dual
```