# A simple SQL query for the Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am looking for a simple Oracle SQL query:
I want to know in which packages in the Oracle database a specific table is been used.
E.g

```
select * 
from   abc
where  table.name = 'XYZ'
```

The output should show me all packages for this table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see PL/SQL Stored Function body in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212295/how-to-see-pl-sql-stored-function-body-in-oracle)

Comment: @user7294900 - no, that thread does not properly answer this Seeker's question. A better answer would mention USER_DEPENDENCIES as the first port of call. I would only turn to USER_SOURCE if I knew (or suspected) the code base made use of dynamic SQL

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE  referenced_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
AND    owner           = 'YOUR_USER'
and type = 'PACKAGE BODY';
```

Comment: I would expand that to "AND TYPE IN ('PACKAGE BODY', 'PROCEDURE'".  I know the OP said specifically for 'packages' but I suspect he is overlooking the possibility of procedures that are not in a package.  Of course, he's also overlooking packages and procedures that (poorly) use dynamic sql to resolve table names at run time . . .  :-)

Comment: @EdStevens - if we're expanding the criteria to standalone units we should include 'FUNCTION' as well.  Also worth noting that occasionally a package spec may reference a table using a `%rowtype` declaration without its body using the table at all. The point about dynamic SQL is a good one.  It's just another reason for avoiding the use of dynamic SQL unless it's absolutely necessary.